# How to detect if audio can't be muted?

Tags: ios, audio, html5-audio, soundmanager2

Is there a way to detect if audio can't be muted? In iOS devices, audio cannot be changed through javascript. I have a button in my app that mutes audio played using SoundManager2 and HTML5 video. This doesn't work in iOS devices. I could check for iOS and handle accordingly, but I am not sure if any other devices are handled this way and its better practice to do more feature detection than device specific changes. I tried checking for the muted parameter and it does change, just doesn't reflect, so I can't do something like this:

```
soundManager.mute();
if (!soundManager.muted) {
  alert("Can't Mute");
}
```

The mute function also just returns null, so its not like I can look at the returned value of that either.

Is there something I am missing or do I need to check for iOS specifically?

Answer (score 0):

I use feature detection. 
First I save the current volume, then I set it to 50%, and check if really is set to 50%
If yes, the device can change volume.
Finally I set the volume back to the original value.

```
var tmpvol = myAudio.volume;
myAudio.volume = 0.5
if (myAudio.volume == 0.5) {
    // true
}
myAudio.volume = tmpvol;
```

Comment: Please explain what that does. Code only answers are frowned upon at Stackoverflow because people are scanning answers for solutions and can't reverse engineer every code snippet there. Since you *already* know, just say what it is. I can figure this out easily, but I still have to stop and study it more than I should have to, to be introduced to the concept your are conveying. Please respect the time of the community and create a title/synopsis/description or introduction for you technical efforts so people know what to expect *before* they study it.